# Declare C function with char* parameter in c#

Tags: c#, dllimport

Using C#.net, how I declare and use this function inside a .dll file:

```
DEMO_API Boolean DEMO_CALL GetVersion(Char* versionBuffer,
    UInt16* versionLengthBuffer);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
    [DllImport("DEMO.dll",
        SetLastError = true,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static byte GetVersion(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder versionBuffer,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder versionLengthBuffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't have the notion of string pointers as such, you can just use a string / int.

Basically to define your own you'd have to do somethign slightly different, but it wouldn't be compatible.

```
public bool GetVersion (string versionBuffer, int versionLengthBuffer)
```

If your using an existing item have a look at [pInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/) for a list of possible signatures.

Comment: The answer didn't work, but entering the link I found pinvoker.com and I got the solution! Thanks!